# How can I make this infinite loop stop when the input repeats?

Tags: c++

It's an exercise that asks us to do the following:

> Write a program that reads lines. For each input line, somebody tells how old he/she is. As a response, the program must say that this person looks younger, and suggest a smaller age.
>
> For ages between 10 and 19 years, the program will suggest exactly 1 less year.
>
> For ages between 20 and 29 years, the program will suggest exactly 2 less years.
>
> For ages between 30 and 39 years, the program will suggest exactly 3 less years.
>
> And so on.
>
> Follow the format of the examples.
>
> Input
>
> Each input line is of the form:
>
> My name is NAME and I am N years old.
>
> Where NAME is a non-empty string without spaces and N is a natural greater than or equal to 10.
>
> Output
>
> For each input case, the output has a line of the form:
>
> NAME, you look younger. I thought you were M years old.
>
> Where NAME is the same string from the input, and M is obtained from N by subtracting a number, which will be 1 if N is between 10 and 19, or 2 if N is between 20 and 29, or 3 if N is between 30 and 39, and so on.

I've tried this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string NAME;
    string my= "My";
    string name="name";
    string is="is";
    string AND="and";
    string I="I";
    string am="am";
    string years="years";
    string old="old.";
    int N;
    
    while(true) {
        cin >> my >> name >> is >> NAME >> AND >> I >> am >> N >> years >> old;

        int division = (N/10);
        if (N >= 10) {
            int M = N-division;
            cout << NAME << ", you look younger. I thought you were " << M << " years old."<< endl;
        }
    }
```

Comment: PSA: All upper-case is usually reserved for constants, and it looks out of place for variable names, at least in accordance with typical C++ coding practices.

Comment: You may need to read in all the input and then step through, looking for spaces, and find the values you need to snip out and convert. What you're doing here with the weird placeholder values is extremely confusing, as this bucks the normal convention of A) Read the entire line. B) Iterate over the line looking for particular values or key offsets. C) Snip out those values into separate variables. C++ can read in "word" by word, in which case you could read data into a `std::vector<std::string>` and then pick out specific offsets, which might be easier.

Comment: I'd use regular expressions for this.

Comment: @paddy Me too, but I'm not someone learning C++ and just getting started.

Comment: The instructions simply tell you to read lines, they say nothing about when to stop reading, and certainly nothing about repeating input. So it would make sense to stop looping when the user enters an empty line, or when they press CTRL-C or CTRL-Z or whatever your terminal requires.  So, for instance, change `while(true) { cin >> ...; ... }` into `while (cin >> ...) { ... }` instead, so the loop breaks when it receives input it is not expecting. On the other hand, you are supposed to be reading *lines*, so you should be using `while (getline(cin, line)) { ... }` and then parsing the `line`.

Comment: In a `while (true)` loop you need `longjmp`, `goto`, `return`, `throw`, `exit`  or `break` (or similar (like `_Exit`)) to be able to exit the loop - you don't have any of those..

Comment: The problem states exactly how the input will be formatted, and does not specify that you should validate it at all. That suggests it's not attempting to test this at all. So you can probably just read a line, then search for `"name is "` and `"I am "` and extract the data that follows.

Comment: What does _"when the input repeats"_ mean? Is that if two lines are exactly the same? That is, if the first line and line 232349879324 are the same, it should abort?

Answer (score 1):

When you need line-based input in C++, use `std::getline`:

```
std::string line;
while (std::getline(std::cin, line))
{
    std::cout << "Read line: " << line << "\n";
}
```

This is the framework for the rest of your program. Although the way you're doing it right now might not be the nicest, your program can be easily converted to extract data from the line by reading from a `std::istringstream` instead of `std::cin`:

```
    std::istringstream iss(line);
    iss >> my >> name >> is >> NAME >> AND >> I >> am >> N >> years >> old;
```

One step beyond that is to recognize that if you don't care about the value of all those strings, there's no point putting them in separate variables. Just replace then with one called `discard`. Also note that you don't need to read the strings for the rest of the line at all.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(std::cin, line))
    {
        std::istringstream iss(line);
        std::string discard;
        std::string name;
        int age;

        iss >> discard >> discard >> discard; // my name is
        iss >> name;
        iss >> discard >> discard >> discard; // and I am
        iss >> age;

        if (iss) {
            age -= age / 10;
            std::cout << name << ", you look younger. I thought you were "
                      << age << " years old.\n";
        }
    }
}
```